# what does Message: Undefined index: host mean?

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

I'm running php/codeigniter. could somone give me any clues?

Comment: In the future, you should just Google something like "php undefined index". Several million answers are immediately presented to you.

Comment: @treeface, one of the goals of SO was to have a site where these types of answers can be found. "You should just Google" is not in the spirit of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

means that something like `$var['host']` was used without being defined beforehand

Answer (score 2):

See also:

[PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable)